# Laravel get 500 error after deploying with deployer to digital ocean

Tags: laravel, php-deployer

Can't figure this one out. I'm hosting my Laravel site on Digital Ocean. To deploy the site I user deployer from deployer.org and their Laravel Recipe. Havn´t really changed anything in their config but whan I deploy I can visit the startpage just fine but any other page renders a 500 error. What gives?

**UPDATE:**

Hi all! the .env file seems fine, it has a KEY and all seemt to be OK there. However, I'm getting this from the nginx error log:

```
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ErrorException: file_put_contents(/var/www/html/mymoodloop.com/shared/storage/framework/views/d4454779c3105d08ab77675858536547a95ae530.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/mymoodloop.com/releases/9/vendor/laravel/f$
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'file_put_conten...', '/var/www/html/m...', 122, Array)
#1 /var/www/html/mymoodloop.com/releases/9/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php(122): file_put_contents('/var/www/html/m...', '<?php $__env->s...', 0)
#2 /var/www/html/mymoodloop.com/releases/9/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.php(122): Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem->put('/var/www/html/m...', '<?php $__env->s...')
#3 /var/www/html/mymoodloop.com/releases/9/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illu
```

And here's the permissions for the storage folder:

```
drwxr-sr-x+ 5 deployer www-data 4096 Jan  7 13:26 storage
```

Comment: Have you checked the php/laravel log files?

Comment: storage/logs tell us what you find, only from here we can shoot in the dark.

Comment: I am not familiar with Deployer.org but checking out the Laravel recipe here https://github.com/deployphp/deployer/blob/master/recipe/laravel.php I am not seeing it create a .env file. I would make sure there is a .env file there and that it has a `APP_KEY`

Comment: Hi guys, not sure how the stack overflow notifications work but I just updated the question with some info from the error logs. Any help is much appreciated, thanks for your answers so far!

Answer (score 0):

It's highly likely that you have forgotten to set the `APP_KEY` as an environment variable, or placed in the `.env` file. Either place your app into debug mode (`APP_DEBUG=true` in your `.env` file) or check the logs in the `storage/logs` directory to see the output of what's gone wrong.

Comment: Please see the update I did for the answer, the app key seems fine, the .env file updates when I run the `php artisan key:generate` command...

Answer (score 0):

After some troubleshooting the site now seems fine. Really unclear what it was that did the trick though but I changed /bootstrap/cache and /storage to 0755 and removed all of the old deployer releases in /releases. This seems to have made the site happy again.

Comment: Are you using `require 'recipe/laravel.php';` in your deploy script? It does a bunch of laravel related things including making sure the storage folder is set up correctly.